# How do I get ExcelData attribute for xunit.net in VS 2015?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, xunit.net

I'm new to xunit, and trying to use the ExcelData attribute in a Theory.  That attribute doesn't appear to exist (no intellisense, build error, has a red squiggle and a suggestion that I create an attribute class).  When I look online, I either find articles assuming that it's there and functional, or articles pointing to getting extensions which seem to no longer be needed with Visual Studio 2015.  I already have a Theory with InlineData working, so I know I've got the basics set up correctly.

I've got references to xunit.abstractions (v 2.0.0.0), xunit.assert (v 2.0.0.2929), and xunit.core (v 2.0.0.2929) in my project.  I have a using statement for Xunit (and Xunit.Extensions which doesn't help).

```
[Theory]
[ExcelData( @"C:\Users\hcy\Documents\MyTestData.xlsx", "Select * from TestData")]
```

What am I missing?  Thanks!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was moved to a sample (whose source code you can copy into your own project).

https://github.com/xunit/samples.xunit/tree/master/ExcelDataExample

Comment: This link is a 404 now, any idea where it went?

Comment: This is no longer available. Wiring up Excel via ADO.NET is no longer a supported scenario.